# Use polymer paper element on angular 2 project

Tags: javascript, polymer, angular, paper-elements

I'm actually trying to use Angular 2 with angular cli and I'm having a problem with polymer paper elements components.

Actually, I link this inside of my `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html"/>
```

But the component doesn't load when I try this:

```
<paper-header-panel class="blue">
    <div class="paper-header">standard</div>
    <div class="content"></div>
  </paper-header-panel>
```

Now, it seems that I can't find the package, the browser tries to request :

```
http://127.0.0.1:4200/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html
```

But nothing is found.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you show me your `bower.json` file?Another quick-tip would be to use either `/bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html` or `bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html` as reference.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779175/polymer-elements-within-angular-2-component/34782260#34782260 about how to use Polymer with Angular2 (don't know about bower though). Some more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981270/bind-angular-2-model-to-polymer-dropdown/33986250, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867952/how-to-use-angular2-ngmodel-for-polymer-paper-input-error-no-value-accessor-fo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356888/polymer-paper-menu-with-angular2

Comment: i'm also getting same issue. can i know if u find any solution