# Polymer paper-menu with Angular2

Tags: angular, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to user Polymer v1.0 elements with Angular2 beta3 and I'm having issues.  Some elements work fine, such as input boxes.

However, when I try and use paper-menu or paper-dropdown-menu it doesn't work.

How can I get this plnkr to work?

http://plnkr.co/edit/2n7xWH0MViPtO8AwZwq2?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>

    <script>
      window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {};
      window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
    </script>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.16/system-polyfills.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.3/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/paper-menu/paper-menu.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html" />

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import all the elements you're using.

The imports were missing for

- paper-item
- paper-listbox

I also think it's important to import full polyfills

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
```

instead of lite

```
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.1.4/lib/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/vCSTObjnHkvgAXXvDImx?p=preview) of the fixed example.

Comment: Thank you, it now renders properly.  However, with your plunker, I cannot select from the dropdown menu.  Or if I try to pre-set a selection by adding: selected="1" to the listbox element, it does not work.  Is there another missing include?

Comment: Selection seems to work fine when you use `paper-menu` instead of `paper-listbox`. I don't know if `paper-listbox` is supposed to be used this way.

Comment: Those polymer elements were pulled right from the polymer demo page.  So I assume paper-listbox is meant to be used inside paper-dropdown-menu (it works fine on the demo page).  If I try using paper-menu inside paper-dropdown-menu it doesn't work.  And it seems that using just paper-listbox on its own doesn't really work either.  Really, what I'm after is a working dropdown select.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I can select from the dropdown here http://plnkr.co/edit/iX12304o1Gah4KhNTgCO?p=preview. Can you provide a link to the demo where you saw it used this way?

Comment: Awesome, it works!  Thanks so much... I could have sworn I tried swapping in paper-menu and it not working, but it works now and that's all that matters.  The polymer 'docs' page shows it correct, however, the polymer 'demo' page shows it using listbox and that's where I pulled it from originally https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-dropdown-menu

Comment: For anyone else looking into this issue, please note that Gunter Zochbauer's solution also enabled proper shadow DOM on the angular my-app component decorator (encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native).  Although, at the moment, I haven't personally tested if it's needed, I'm guessing it is since I believe Polymer uses proper shadow DOM.

Comment: I also don't know `ViewEncapsulation.Native` is necessary (I guess not). I tried it while investigating the problem and forgot to remove it again. Glad to hear you got it working :)