# How to use Angular2 ngModel for Polymer paper-input? ERROR: No value accessor for ''

Tags: typescript, angular, polymer-1.0

This is my first question,
I'm using angular2.beta.8, polymer 1.0, typescript.
I'm having a problem when I use ngModel data binding with
polymer paper-input element

Basically nothing more than an element with ngModel and variable in the class.
    
Running that creates this error: No value accessor for ''

I started to use polymers with angular 2 just recently, and maybe this is noobie question, but I can't seem to find any information covering this topic.

I have searched for this error for quite some while and I feel like I have no options left other than ask you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `ngDefaultControl`

```
<paper-input [(ngModel)]="myModel" ngDefaultControl></paper-input>
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5360

Comment: You are god. Thank you. :)

Comment: there's a typo on the closing tag. <paper-intput>, it should be </paper-input>.
trivial, but does not allow to copy&paste the snippet :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fr.Usai ! Fixed.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I remember it used to work but with angular 2.1.0 it doesn't. Anything changed?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Haven't used it since then.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Do you know of any way you can avoid using `ngDefaultControl`? I have a wrapping container as a layer of abstraction on a 3rd party component (ngPrime autocomplete) with `formControl`.

Comment: You shouldn't need `ngDefaultControl` at all with Angular components. Angular components should implement `ControlValueAccessor`.