# Angular2 Template parse errors: Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template

Tags: angular, polymer

This is the Angular2 template:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Country">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="GetAdmin1s($event)">
            <paper-item *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.Id}}">{{country.Name}}</paper-item>
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

I am getting this error:

```
"Template parse errors:
Property binding ngFor not used by any directive on an embedded template (""dropdown-content" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="GetAdmin1s($event)">
            [ERROR ->]<paper-item *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.Id}}">{{country.Name}}</paper-item>
 "): LocationComponent@4:12
Property binding ngForCountry not used by any directive on an embedded template (""dropdown-content" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="GetAdmin1s($event)">
            [ERROR ->]<paper-item *ngFor="let country of countries" value="{{country.Id}}">{{country.Name}}</paper-item>
 "): LocationComponent@4:12"
```

Countries variable is defined as:

```
public countries: Array<Country> = [];
```

What is wrong with my use of ngFor? Why is it looking for ngForCountry?

Comment: You sure you're running angular2 >= beta-17?

Comment: Please post a plunkr, [I'm unable to reproduce this](http://plnkr.co/edit/j9e98h2sNv49Md9i95Sn?p=preview) (feel free to fork that one)

Comment: I just upgraded to rc.1 and I'm still getting an error. I'm trying to do the plunkr with all the dependencies involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Just try might help`**

```
  <paper-dropdown-menu label="Country">
    <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry" (ngModelChange)="GetAdmin1s($event)">
        <paper-item ngFor #country [ngForOf]="countries" value="{{country.Id}}">{{country.Name}}</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: I think this worked. I'm getting an error in another part of the code instead. "No value accessor for '' in [selectedCountry in LocationComponent@3:48]"

Comment: @JonasArcangel for the `value accessor` error message see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202543/ngmodel-binding-on-polymer-dropdown-angular2

Comment: @mayur that's quite weird that this works. This `ngFor` syntax is supposed to only work on `<template>`. Very interesting find!

Answer (score 0):

You can try :
*ngFor="#country of countries"

Comment: I don't think this syntax is used anymore. I get "No provider for e! (e -> e)" error.