# How to remove "property binding not used by any directive" error in Dart Angular2 tutorial?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, angular2-template

I am doing this tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/tutorial/toh-pt2.html

Now, I am trying to get list of heroes on the page. There is error while compiling template from tutorial. This is template: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/toh-2/dart/lib/app_component.dart#L13. I am getting this error:

```
Build error:
Transform TemplateCompiler on ng2_hero_app|lib/app_component.ng_meta.json threw error: Template parse errors:
Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
      <h2>My Heroes</h2>
      <ul class="heroes">
        [ERROR ->]<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
          [class.selected]="hero == selectedHero"
          (click)"): AppComponent@3:8
Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template ("
        </li>
      </ul>
```

What I tried?

- I tried it by myself first, got error. I copy-pasted code from github then and I am getting same error.
- I tried to re-run `pub get` (I thought there is some error like missing some npm package when developing node module).
- I tried to research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221231/angular2-template-parse-errors-property-binding-ngfor-not-used-by-any-directive). This post says, that I should rewrite code of `*ngFor` directive. Well, I tried, templated compiled successfully, but I got nothing on page.

This is my current app_component.dart code: https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/angular2-hero-app/blob/master/lib/app_component.dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might miss `COMMON_DIRECTIVES` in `pubspec.yaml`

```
  transformers:
  - angular2/transform/codegen:
      platform_directives: 'package:angular2/src/common/directives.dart#CORE_DIRECTIVES'
```

This is RC syntax which is not yet available for Dart

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
```

in beta it is

```
<li *ngFor="#hero of heroes"
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/825 and the linked wiki document where `PLATFORM_PIPES` are mentioned which can be made available globally this way as well.