# Can the Polymer paper-dropdown-menu be bound using ngControl?

Tags: forms, data-binding, typescript, angular, polymer

I am trying to create a form in Angular2 using the Polymer `paper-dropdown-menu` control. Is there a way to bind the selected value of the dropdown to the control in my component? I have tried everything with no luck. Has anyone gotten over this hurdle?

An example of a working `paper-input` is:

template:

```
<paper-input type="password"
             ngControl="password"
             ngDefaultControl>
</paper-input>
```

component:

```
constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {

    this.loginForm = fb.group({
        password: new Control("")
    });
}
```

Is there something similar for `paper-dropdown-menu`? Either binding to the value or the text itself would be fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom `ControlValueAccessor`. I didn't succeed using a `ControlValueAccessor` for the `paper-dropdown-menu` itself but for the `paper-menu` or `paper-listbox` inside the `paper-dropdown-menu` like

```
const PAPER_MENU_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
    NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => PaperMenuControlValueAccessor), multi: true});


@Directive({
  selector: 'paper-listbox',
  host: {'(iron-activate)': 'onChange($event.detail.selected)'},
  providers: [PAPER_MENU_VALUE_ACCESSOR]

})  
export class PaperMenuControlValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_:any) => {
  };
  onTouched = () => {
  };

  constructor(private _renderer:Renderer, private _elementRef:ElementRef) {
    console.log('PaperMenuControlValueAccessor');
  }

  writeValue(value:any):void {
    //console.log('writeValue', value);
    this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'selected', value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn:(_:any) => {}):void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn:() => {}):void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

See also

- [ngModel Binding on Polymer dropdown (Angular2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202543/ngmodel-binding-on-polymer-dropdown-angular2/37202613#37202613)
- [Bind angular 2 model to polymer dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981270/bind-angular-2-model-to-polymer-dropdown/33986250)